# Is this an ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 1 bug, and what's the work-around?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dictionary, parameters, preview

I'm using this code in ASP.NET MVC 2 preview 1:

```
    public ActionResult List(long id, [DefaultValue(0)] long? commentId)
    {
        var model = UserComment.ForRefId(id);
        PageTitle = string.Format("Comments for '{0}'", 
                                  SetCommentThread(id).Subject);
        ViewData[MvcApplication.SAnchor] = commentId;
        return View("List", model);
    }
```

When I use a valid URL argument such as "/Comment/List/22638", I get the error:

> The parameters dictionary contains an
>   invalid entry for parameter
>   'commentId' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   List(Int64,
>   System.Nullable`1[System.Int64])' in
>   'ThreadsMVC.Controllers.CommentController'.
>   The dictionary contains a value of
>   type 'System.Int32', but the parameter
>   requires a value of type
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]'.
>   Parameter name: parameters

If I change the declaration to:

```
    public ActionResult List(long id, [DefaultValue(0)] int? commentId)
```

The code runs fine. Is this something I'm doing wrong, or a problem with the reflection being too type strict for Int32 vs Int64? And what can I do to fix it? Cast the long as a string?

Comment: This works for me in MVC1. Can you reproduce the error in MVC1?

Comment: Haven't tried MVC 1 yet .. since this is a new project, I'm "looking ahead" and enjoying the new template support so much I don't want to go back to MVC 1. This is the version that makes MVC more compelling to me :)

Comment: I haven't tested this in MVC 1, I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more readable/less messy, and works in MVC 1, too:

```
public ActionResult List(long id, long? commentId)
{
    var model = UserComment.ForRefId(id);
    PageTitle = string.Format("Comments for '{0}'", 
                              SetCommentThread(id).Subject);
    ViewData[MvcApplication.SAnchor] = commentId.GetValueOrDefault(0);
```

Comment: Thanks Craig (and Spencer). I also needed to update my routing to support the second ID, and I have it working now.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 public ActionResult List(long id, [DefaultValue((long)0)] long? commentId)
```

Comment: Convenient shorthand: [DefaultValue(0L)]

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to the global.asax Application_Start method

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();
```

For more on this, see Scott's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/14/update-on-asp-net-mvc-3-rc2-and-a-workaround-for-a-bug-in-it.aspx

Also see [jQuery Sort and MVC Stopped Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495896/jquery-sort-and-mvc-stopped-working/6802569#6802569)