# jQuery Sort and MVC Stopped Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-sortable

I am getting the following error when JQuery Sort calls my sort action:

The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter 'DonationIDS' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.EmptyResult SortDonations(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32])' in 'Vol.Web.Areas.ActivityArea.Controllers.DonationController'. The dictionary contains a value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Vol.Models.Token]', but the parameter requires a value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'.
Parameter name: parameters

jQuery:

```
$("#dlist").sortable({
        handle: '.sorthandle',
        update: function () {
            var order = $('#dlist').sortable('toArray');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/activity/donation/sortdonations',

                data: { DonationIDS: order },
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true
            });
        }
    });
```

Post Values:

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
DonationIDS 1
DonationIDS 8
Source
DonationIDS=1&DonationIDS=8
```

MVC Action:

```
 public EmptyResult SortDonations(List<int> DonationIDS)
        {


            int order = 0;
            foreach (int i in DonationIDS)
            {
                donationRepository.UpdateSortOrder(i, order);
                order++;
            }


            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

It was working perfectly but now it seems to reference another class, Token.  Any ideas what is going on or where to start looking?

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`I changed by action to use a string and it resolved the issue.

```
     [HttpPost]
        public EmptyResult SortDonations(string[] donationorder)


{

    int order = 0; 
    foreach (var i in donationorder)
    {
        donationRepository.UpdateSortOrder(Convert.ToInt32(i), order);
        order++;
    }


    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to the global.asax Application_Start method

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();
```

For more on this, see Scott's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/14/update-on-asp-net-mvc-3-rc2-and-a-workaround-for-a-bug-in-it.aspx